# What does "organise" mean in the following passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Next, the screenplay is sent to a producer. That person **organises** the making of the film. He or she will manage the money and hire the film crew.

1. [transitive] **organise something** to arrange for something to happen or to be provided

   2. [transitive] **organise something** to arrange something or the parts of something into a particular order or structure

1 or 2? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb [**organize**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/organize) (*organise* written with an s is the way they spell it in the UK) in this passage means to make arrangements for something such as an event to happen. The event can be pretty much anything that involves some form of organization (planning, in other words)—a meeting, a party, the making of a movie, a theatrical play and so on and so forth:

> They organized a meeting between the teachers and students.